# Change image size

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to change the image size (make it look smaller than the original).

I tried with the next code but the image still shows at its original size.

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{method.eps}
\caption{Overall process}
\label{fig:method}
\end{figure}
```

I am using TeXnic Center with profile latex>ps>pdf

**Update:**

It seems to work now but I do not why

I first built the project with the profile latex => ps and then I built it with latex=>ps=>pdf

Comment: Is it a tall image?

Comment: No, it is a horizontal image.

Comment: Can you remove the extension `.eps` and try again and complete your code into a full one (making a minimal working example)?

Comment: I think its because the file does not include meta-data information. [similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21627/image-from-includegraphics-showing-in-wrong-image-size)

Comment: Take the [one in this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47344/3235) as I'm sure that it works properly.

Comment: @Enrique If the problem is in missing bounding box information, you should be able to see it in the `log` file.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Use the `scale=0.5` option in the `\includegraphics` command to shrink the image to 50% of its original size. That is, `\includegraphics[width=50mm,scale=0.5]{method.eps}`. You can use a different percentage if needed.

Comment: It did not work

Comment: @Enrique - please be a bit more specific as to what doesn't work. Do you get an error message? Is there no error message but the image is still too large? If so, what's the original image size?

Comment: It did not change the image size. I have fixed the problem. See updated question.

Comment: What is the use of `{method.eps}`?

Comment: It is the image. ".eps" is an extension just like,  ".png" and ".jpg" extensions

Comment: @Enrique Sems like you can't combine `scale` and `width`. But if you only use `scale` it works for me.

Comment: Is it possible to scale the width and height independently? I know this syntax is wrong, but something like `\includegraphics[scalewidth=1,scaleheight=1.5]{method.eps}` ?

Answer (score 51):

I usually just do `\includegraphics[width=0.7\columnwidth]{figure}`, where `0.7` is the fraction of the column width.

This is useful for IEEE double column papers.

Comment: `\linewidth` might be a wee bit safer, as it usually works well also inside `\parbox`es and `minipage`s.

Comment: This is more copy-paste friendly than the accepted answer, which requires a different number for each image.

Comment: What if I have two images side by side, would it be okay to use 0.7?

Answer (score 21):

`\includegraphics[scale=0.25] {name.jpg}`

This works well. `scale=0.25` is to shrink the image to 0.25 but can use any ratio.

Comment: Welcome, what information does your answer add compared to the accepted answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B the original answer uses both width= and scale=, which is not a good idea. Use either but not both.

Answer (score -2):

**Based on my experience, I added [scale=0.25] after \includegraphics [scale=0.25] is used to reduce the image to a Scale of 0.25. However there could use other ratios.**

***Previously I added [scale=0.25] :***

```
\includegraphics{Research methodology.png}}
```

***After I add [scale=0.25] the result is as follows:***

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{Research methodology.png}}
```

*And examples of other formats like this :*

```
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{Research methodology.png}}
```

Comment: Better keep away from `\centerline`, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311294/36296