# Ideas for a physical (non-PDF-digital) Bookmark

Tags: formatting, book-design

I'd like to make **a physical bookmark**, so that readers can leave inside the page numbers *to mark where to continue reading*. I haven't ever seen any examples of this through the site. This would be a piece of cardboard that may have some printing in words on it.

I'm open for any ideas. Some things I'm looking for (not required as answer):

- a stylish example, of what LaTeX can do
- to customize a paper size
- to replicate the marker many times in a page to cut several markers from 1 sheet

So I've already wrote a book and auto-published with LaTeX. I've made the inside, the book cover. And now this last part would be great. I'm looking to promote [mysite.com] where I have more material alike to the book. I've tried to make a `mwe` but am not satisfied with the result. (I've used `tcolorbox` but this was just a casual random experiment).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,landscape]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{question}
{colback=gray!20,colframe=gray,fonttitle=\bfseries,
title=mysite.com~}

\begin{document} 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{multicols}{3}

\begin{minipage}{6.7cm}\begin{question}
site content is ... \lipsum[11] \par 
\end{question}\end{minipage} \hspace*{1cm}

\begin{minipage}{6.7cm}\begin{question}
site content is ... \lipsum[11] \par 
\end{question}\end{minipage} \hspace*{1cm}

\begin{minipage}{6.7cm}\begin{question}
site content is ... \lipsum[11] \par 
\end{question}\end{minipage} \hspace*{1cm}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

---

#### Some notes on customization

- Maybe it'd be desirable to have a number book-format to marker **ratios**? ([Meaning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55502/modern-book-design-margins-and-typed-area)).
- Following the prior, on a personal note:

  - I'm planning to do this for a A6 sized booklet. What should be the ideal size/s of the bookmark?
  - The <del>marker</del> bookmark is to be done in a <del>paper</del> cardboard that resembles the color, and perhaps even texture, of wood. So it's ok if black letters are used, but white letters are not very encouraged. Hence my dissatisfaction with my own `mwe`.

#### Some points to develop

2 ideas from `cfr`, with which I agree:

> the ideal bookmark does **not obscure content** when reading, even if the marker is left in place. This means that the ideal bookmark is typically longer than the height of the paper but very thin. The ribbon markers sewn into traditional bindings are very good, but portable markers can serve the same function.
>
> That is, good bookmarks are like good typography - you don't notice them. They do **not draw attention** to themselves, but simply facilitate focusing on the book's content (or books' contents, in the portable case).

The next point however, I'm uncertain. Opinions?

> ..But you obviously cannot make markers of this kind from cardboard and you certainly can't use them to draw attention to a website!

Explanation: I write short pieces in website and send to some people to beta-test. These pieces are latter to be part of a next book. So there is a good deal of pre-book, and book-alike, materials. Hence I think it'd be ok to refer that in a bookmark for the book and it's readers. Pros/Cons?

---

#### Wrapping up

What is the expected material to be proper for a bookmark?

Comment: minor other question, in this `mwe`: how can I apply `\center`  to `title=mysite.com`?

Comment: I don't see what kind of answer can reasonably be given as the question currently stands. I would have thought that grey boxes and black lettering on wood-coloured cardboard would look pretty dire, myself, so I obviously differ in tastes rather significantly. What is or are `a number book-format to marker ratios`?

Comment: If you don't want white letters, why are you using white? Why, in fact, are you using coloured boxes? If you can say what you actually want, that is one thing, but currently you don't seem very sure. Perhaps you should ask on the graphics design SE first?

Comment: @cfr Any answer is good. No standards, I just want to explore possible versions. Since no one asked this before I think it may be interesting to start with some intents. A dark color ink on brown paper may be quite dire, but not impossible to cope with: I like [Virilio's _Velocidad y Política_](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41D37TM9DYL._SX327_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg) with that style.

Comment: @cfr I don't intend to use white ink. Coloured box is just the first hint I got to one possible mwe. I'm not ok with my mwe, that's why I'm asking: I'm looking for ideas for bookmarks. And I'm open. I just placed a mwe to show that I've thought about some features and gave it some time of working on it, not asking out of the blue. Graphics design is a good possibility. But since I'm working in LaTeX thought best to check here first. And the community is good. Thanks for comments!

Comment: We do more implementation that design, though. If they tell you what you want, we can probably do it in LaTeX. (Fighting chance, anyway.)

Comment: And, yes. I'm aware of the different discussions and methods for calculating margins etc. for typographic design. But I still have no idea what you mean. What does any of that have to do with bookmarks? Are you suggesting that the classical designs are deficient not only in being deprecated by contemporary aesthetics, but also because they fail to tell you how big your bookmarks should be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45409/discussion-between-nilon-and-cfr).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I say, I think this is unanswerable. But, hey, it doesn't usually stop people.

First, some standard bookmarks. If it is going on wood-effect paper, I'd say you want something without much background, but since you're using colour boxes, I guess you don't agree.

[image: standardish]

Now for something with a bit more sparkle.

[image: sparkly]

And with a take away message.

[image: take away message]

Code for included graphics (cat codes, duck codes, tree codes, tram codes ...) is available elsewhere on this site ;). Cauldron variant availabe on application.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[vscale=.95,hscale=.975]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse,skins}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings,fit,backgrounds}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{PTSansCaption,PTSerif}
\NewTColorBox{marker}{ O {blue!50!cyan} O {magenta} }{% page 197
  skin=enhanced,
  frame style={upper left=#1, upper right=#2, lower left=#2,lower right=#1},
  interior style={white},
  fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
  center title,
  title=mysite.com,
  width=.245\textwidth,
  nobeforeafter,
  hyphenationfix,
  halign=center,
  boxsep=.25mm,
  fontupper=\sffamily,
  toptitle=1mm,
  bottomtitle=1mm,
  coltitle=black,
  title filled=false,
  colback=white,
  colbacktitle=white,
}
\NewTColorBox{bookmark}{ s O {blue!50!cyan} O {magenta} O {blue} }{% page 197
  skin=enhanced,
  frame style={upper left=#2, upper right=#3, lower left=#3,lower right=#2},
  interior style={white, opacity=0.5},
  colbacktitle=white,
  coltitle=black!85!#4,
  colupper=black!60!#4,
  opacitybacktitle=.25,
  IfBooleanTF={#1}{fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\Large}{fonttitle=\bfseries\Large},
  IfBooleanTF={#1}{fontupper=\sffamily}{},
  center title,
  title=mysite.com,
  width=.245\textwidth,
  nobeforeafter,
  hyphenationfix,
  halign=center,
  boxsep=.25mm,
  toptitle=1mm,
  bottomtitle=1mm,
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{marker}
  \lipsum[11]
\end{marker}
\begin{marker}[gray][gray]
  \lipsum[11]
\end{marker}
\begin{marker}[black][white]
  \lipsum[11]
\end{marker}
\begin{bookmark}*
  \lipsum[11]
\end{bookmark}
\medskip

\noindent
\begin{bookmark}
  \lipsum[11]
\end{bookmark}
\begin{bookmark}[orange!25!red!60!brown][yellow!40!brown][brown]
  \lipsum[11]
\end{bookmark}
\begin{bookmark}[blue][green][blue!75!green]
  \lipsum[11]
\end{bookmark}
\begin{bookmark}[blue!25!white][white!25!blue][blue!75!gray]
  \lipsum[11]
\end{bookmark}
\newpage
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [rotate=90] (c) {\includegraphics[width=100mm]{cath-gadael-chartref}};
  \node (a) [anchor=south, font=\itshape\LARGE, rotate=90] at (c.north) {Don't leave home without it!};
  \node (b) [anchor=south, font=\Huge\bfseries, rotate=90] at (a.north) {mysite.com};
  \node [fit=(c) (a) (b), line width=.5mm, double=red!25, draw=red!75!black, rounded corners=10pt] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hskip 10mm
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (c) {\includegraphics[width=130mm]{coeden-nadolig-2014-hwyaden}};
  \node (a) [anchor=north, font=\itshape\LARGE, text=blue!25] at (c.south) {Spruce it up!};
  \node (b) [anchor=south, font=\Huge\bfseries, text=blue!75!black] at (c.north) {mysite.com};
  \scoped[on background layer]{%
    \node [fit=(c) (a) (b), draw=blue!50, line width=2.5mm, rounded corners=25pt, inner xsep=0pt, bottom color=black, top color=blue!15] {};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: All good bookmarks feature cats.

Comment: +1 the one with the bus seems nice: it has good proportion of text and image and good size ratio between hight and width. is it possible to do markers with other packages? Trying to figure it out ...

Comment: @cfr how do you re-size an image at title? I tried this with the standards [`[width=\textwidth]`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39147/scale-image-to-page-width) and [`[width=50mm,scale=0.5]`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64836/change-image-size#64843) and wouldn't compile. What am I missing?

Comment: @nilon What do you mean? You can see I've used similar keys for `\includegraphics` in some of my examples. Of course you can make markers with other packages. Or none. They are just boxes, after all. I guess I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I got your code and used this part `title=mysite.com` and tried to include an image before the name of the site. the problem is it only applies for original size of image. so if I use `\includegraphics{./flashlight-black.png}` all is ok. but if I add the optional `[scale=0.5]` in between as option, it fails to compile. all together: this line doesn't work and I can't find out why: `title=\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{./image.png}site.com`. ... oops! just solved it all 2 mins later by putting that whole code inside of `{}`. thanks anyway. best

Comment: @nilon Was just going to suggest enclosing in `{}`. The square brackets are probably confusing the parser.