# The origin of filecontents

Tags: packages

Does anyone know why the `filecontents` environment was introduced?

What is the purpose of packing it all in one file, but without using a tarball?

Comment: some people don't know how to use tar or zip.  `filecontents` keeps everything together in one `.tex` file.

Comment: Echoing @barbarabeeton's comment (from the [`source2e` documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf), p 361): "The environment `filecontents` is intended for passing the contents of packages, options, or other files along with a document in a single file."

Comment: I would add that some computing environments forbid binary data breaching firewalls, whereas ASCII is, with caveats, allowed

Comment: Example for an `.eps` file inclusion. : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47341/can-you-embed-an-image-so-it-doesnt-need-to-be-stored-as-a-separate-file

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a natural extension of the ideas of `docstrip` that extracts comments and writes out the `.sty` and `.cls` files of the LaTeX distribution. It could have been written in perl or something but writing it in TeX makes it more portable to anyone who has tex at all.

Note that in 1991-1993 while latex2e was being developed, perl (introduced 1987) and a portable zip (info-zip introduced 1989) were not as commonly installed as they are today. Even now it is much easier to add small `.csv` data files or local `.sty` files to examples posted to this site by using `filecontents` than it is to post them as separate files and have to give instructions about saving and file names, or posting to some other site as a zip or tar file and then hoping people on windows can unpack it.

Comment: Wow, in 1993 they already prepared latex2e for use with stackexchange ;-)

Comment: @arney well we were probably thinking more of `comp.text(.tex)` but it's the same questions, just recycled:-)